# Are there plans to self-fund/self-govern the development of Ethereum software?

Tags: governance

Are there any plans to get this project self-funded and self-governanced? Maybe some schemes as in DASH? They have developed an incentivisation model of network participants by dividing block reward into 3 parts.

1st part (45%) goes to miners, 2nd part (45%) goes to full-nodes (masternode in DASH), and 3rd (10%) goes to the budget, which is to be spent among different proposals (including core team reward) based on poll results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I suggest you start reading the [whitepaper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) to find out what ethereum is really about: *A next-generation smart contract and decentralized application platform*.

To finance development, Ethereum distributed the initial allocation of Ether via a 42-day public crowdsale, netting 31,591 bitcoins, worth $18,439,086 at that time, in exchange for about 60,102,216 Ether.